# Partial view based on a query from Data Base

Tags: c#, .net, linq, model-view-controller

I am showing search results same as searching groups on facebook.

[image: Check showing results here]

I have a relationship Table named `CommunityUser` in Database having attributes `CommunityID` and `UserID` .

Using Partial View I want to show if `User` not already joined that Community/Group that it will show **Join Button** else if user already joined that community it will show **Leave button**.

Complicated step for me is these results are showing with foreach loop. Here is my **Partial View Class** code. I am considering that I am passing query that will return me 1 if that communityID exist against that userID in CommunityUser table else return 0.

```
@model IEnumerable<FYP.Models.CommunityUser>

@ViewBag.UserID = db.Users.Where(u=> u.UserName == User.Identity.Name).SingleOrDefault();
@ViewBag.Count = (from CommunityUser in FYP.Models where CommunityUser.Id = UserID && CommunityUser.CommunityID = ViewBag.ComID select CommunityUser).Count();

@if (ViewBag.Count)
{
    <button>@Html.ActionLink("Leave", "LeaveCommunity", new { id = ViewBag.ComID })</button>
}
else
{
    <button>@Html.ActionLink("Join", "joinCommunity", new { id = ViewBag.ComID })</button>
}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: PArtial view not working with this query